# Why this expansion inside expansion pattern doesn't work?

Tags: shell, scripting, zsh, variable-expansion

Suppose you have something like:

```
$ a=(fooa foob foox)
```

Then you can do:

```
$ b=(${(M)a:#*(a|b)})
```

To select a's elements matching the pattern.

So you have:

```
$ print ${(qq)b}
'fooa' 'foob'
```

Then you expect to build the pattern in some dynamic way, so you have it in another variable, say:

```
$ p="*(a|b)"
```

And you expect this:

```
$ b=(${(M)a:#$p})
```

Would work the same as before, as the documentation says, but it doesn't:

```
$ print ${(qq)b} 
''
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because zsh tries to select `$p`'s value literally (a plain string text) in this case:

```sh
a=('*(a|b)' fooa foob)
p="*(a|b)"
b=(${(M)a:#$p})
print ${(qq)b}
;#⇒'*(a|b)'
```

We could tell zsh to treat `$p`'s expansion as patterns rather than literal values explicitly by a `${~spec}` form.

> ${~spec}
>
> Turn on the [`GLOB_SUBST`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-GLOB_005fSUBST) option for the evaluation of spec; if the ‘`~`’ is doubled, turn it off. When this option is set, the string resulting from the expansion will be interpreted as a pattern anywhere that is possible, such as in filename expansion and filename generation and pattern-matching contexts like the right hand side of the ‘`=`’ and ‘`!=`’ operators in conditions.
>
> -- [`zshexpn(1): Expansion, Parameter Expansion`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion)

In this case, we could use it like this:

```sh
a=(fooa foob foox)
p="*(a|b)"
b=(${(M)a:#${~p}}) ;# tell zsh treat as a pattern for `$p`
print ${(qq)b}
;#⇒'fooa' 'foob'
```

---

Note: It gives some hints in the parameter expansion flag `b` for storing patterns in variable values:

> `b`
>
> Quote with backslashes only characters that are special to pattern matching. This is useful when the contents of the variable are to be tested using [`GLOB_SUBST`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-GLOB_005fSUBST), including the `${~...}` switch.
>
> Quoting using one of the q family of flags does not work for this purpose since quotes are not stripped from non-pattern characters by [`GLOB_SUBST`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-GLOB_005fSUBST). In other words,
>
> ```
>    pattern=${(q)str}
>    [[ $str = ${~pattern} ]]
> ```
>
> works if `$str` is ‘`a*b`’ but not if it is ‘`a b`’, whereas
>
> ```
>    pattern=${(b)str}
>    [[ $str = ${~pattern} ]]
> ```
>
> is always true for any possible value of `$str`.
>
> -- [`zshexpn(1): Expansion, Parameter Expansion, Parameter Expansion Flags`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags)